# how can i stop these 2 wordpress functions from interfering with each other?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, themes

i have a specific word press theme and a plugin for counting downloads.... however when i activate the plugin it makes all my "featured thumbnails" disappear for all the post types in my wordpress... in other words there is no "featured image box" when adding any kind of post AFTER i activate the plugin......

after looking through my theme code and the plugin code i believe i have found the problem but i am not sure hoe to fix it.....

the theme i am using has the following function

```
// Add Thumbnail support
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) { // Adding thumbnail support to all post types.

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'store', 'dlm_download', 'service', 'album', 'mixtape', 'merch', 'photos', 'video' , 'download' , 'homebanner', 'post' ) );
add_image_size('storeimage', 200, 200, true); //Store homepage Thumbnails
add_image_size('beat_page', 160, 160, true); // Single beat page
add_image_size('photo', 200, 200, true); // Thumbnail image
add_image_size('photowidget', 165, 165, true); // Thumbnail image
add_image_size('videowidget', 270, 151, true); // Thumbnail image
add_image_size('photobig', 570, 570, true); // Image for single page
add_image_size('videoimage', 273, 200, true); // Video Gallery Homepage Thumbnails
add_image_size('homebannerimage', 920, 350, true); //Homepage Banner Image
add_image_size('featuredimage', 580, 250, true); //Post Featured image Image 580x250
}
```

and then the plugin has the following function

```
public function compatibility() {
    // Post thumbnail support
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' ) ) {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'thumbnail' );
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'thumbnail' );
    } else {

        // Get current supported
        $current_support = get_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        // This can be a bool or array. If array we merge our post type in, if bool ignore because it's like a global theme setting.
        if ( is_array( $current_support ) ) {
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array_merge( $current_support, array( 'dlm_download' ) ) );
        }

        add_post_type_support( 'download', 'thumbnail' );
    }
}
```

i noticed they both use "add_theme_support" , "post-thumbnails" and a few other similar things...... not sure why the two functions are interfering with each other or how i could fix it...... i tried to add the "dlm_download" post type (this is the post type for the the plugin) to the theme functions array of post types and it didnt make any difference.....

i tried to totally remove the thumbnail function from the plugin and kept getting a "failed to call header : head already called" error....

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line in your theme

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'store', 'dlm_download', 'service', 'album', 'mixtape', 'merch', 'photos', 'video' , 'download' , 'homebanner', 'post' ) );
```

to

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Comment: WONDERFUL!
THANKS THAT SEEMS TO HAVE DONE IT!

Comment: Great to hear. It would be nice to see this question resolved then.